# Renderscript generating corrupted result without using CPU driver on some devices

Tags: android, renderscript

I have written an algorithm to generate HSV color wheel programatically by using Renderscript.

The renderscript implemenation is generating nice results on most devices, but on some devices (for example Moto E) I need to switch to CPU driver by using shell command

```
adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1
```

Can any one explain me why I need to do this, and if it is  possible to do this via code.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _generating corrupted result_?

Comment: sorry, i meant i am calculating color at each pixel, and it is getting seen as noisy ! i didnt get a chance to debug as someone else reported it ! i have asked for device and i will be debugging it my self as well !

Comment: Are you using _forEach_ to convert the values per pixel or some other method, for example binding bitmap data as array or Allocation? I've faced some problems with row alignment and am wondering could this be the case with your code too. This is with binding data into RenderScript.

Comment: Two comparison screenshots would be very helpful.